# Insert a position in a linked list Java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

My question is: Write a function that inserts a new item into a Linked List of integers at the given position.
My code is:

```java
public static SinglyLinkedListNode insert_at_position(SinglyLinkedListNode head, int val, int pos) {
    
        SinglyLinkedListNode temp = head;
        
        if (pos == 0)
        {
            SinglyLinkedListNode newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode(val);
            newNode = temp;
            head = newNode;
        }
        
        else if (pos > 0)
        {
            SinglyLinkedListNode newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode(val);
            newNode = temp;
            head = newNode;
            
            for (int i = 0 ; i <= pos; i++)
            {
                  temp = head.next;
                  if (i == pos)
                  {
                      head.next = newNode;
                      newNode = temp;
                  }  
            }
        }
        return head;
 }
```

My code just prints alot of 1's. What is wrong with it?

Comment: You're creating newNode, and then you're just overwriting it? It might help to see more of your code. For instance, you aren't printing anything here. Also, the code that calls this method would be useful to see. And we can't debug it without having the main method.

Comment: you can refer from here, [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insert-a-node-at-a-specific-position-in-a-linked-list/)

Comment: Just debug your code. Step through it, inspect variables, and see how your code is not doing what it should do. For the correct solution: you can find it with a simple search.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- The code creates a new node, assigns it to `newNode`, and then immediately assigns `temp` to `newNode`, thereby losing the reference to the newly created node
- `temp` is initialised with the value of `head`, then `newNode` gets the value of `temp` and then `head` gets the value of `temp`. This means you have set `head` to ... `head`, a no-operation.
- The loop performs `temp = head.next;` in each iteration. This will always put the *same* reference in `temp`... every time it executes. So the number of iterations of the loop becomes irrelevant. `temp` will always refer to the second node in the list. It would make more sense to do `temp = temp.next`
- In the last iteration you set `head.next = newNode;` ... even ignoring what you did with `temp`. This assignment uses nothing that was done during the iterations of the loop. It might as well be executed outside of the loop.
- The last statement `newNode = temp` is doing nothing useful. `newNode` is never used after that statement, so it might as well not be there. It would have made more sense if it were `newNode.next = temp`. That will effectively link `newNode` to a potentially next node.
- The loop iterates too many times. As you have used `pos == 0` to insert the new node at the start of the list, `pos == 1` should insert the new node after the `head` node, for which *no* iteration is necessary. Only when `pos > 2` you need iteration(s).

Here is a corrected version:

```
public static SinglyLinkedListNode insert_at_position(SinglyLinkedListNode head, 
                                                      int val, int pos) {        
    SinglyLinkedListNode newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode(val);
    if (pos == 0) {
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    } else if (pos > 0) {
        SinglyLinkedListNode temp = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        newNode.next = temp.next;
        temp.next = newNode;
    }
    return head;
}
```